# KnockoutJS apply binding to form returned from Ajax

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I have a button thats applied to the DOM after an ajax

```
<input type="submit" data-bind="click: save" />
```

The `save` call is not triggered from without my ViewModel, presumably Knockout is not aware from this new binding within the DOM.

```
 var Model = function()
 {
      this.save = function(data, event)
      {
           alert("test");
      }
 }
```

How can I reapply the binding so that this new HTML is picked up and the `save` binding works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading new content, you can apply bindings to the save button, with the part of your model that contains the `save` method, using `ko.applyBindings(model, targetElement)`:

### Example:

```js
var vm = {
    load: function() {
        // insert new content
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 
        '<input id="btLoad" \
                type="button" value="save" \
                data-bind="click: save" />';
        
        // apply bindings to new elements
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('btLoad'));
    },
    save: function() {
        alert('saved');
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js">
</script>

<input type="button" value="load" data-bind="click: load"/>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: This is proving extremely difficult. I think KnockoutJS was meant to to fix this kind of thing. The element does not have an ID, so I have tried to get it like so `ko.applyBindings(pm, $("#defaultModal .modal-body form").get());`. But that hasn't worked. I get the error `Uncaught Error: ko.applyBindings: first parameter should be your view model; second parameter should be a DOM node`

Comment: Ah ha its worked with `ko.applyBindings(pm, $("#defaultModal .modal-body form").get(0));`. But what happens if `#defaultModal .modal-body form` is changed by another ajax request - will this call then fail as `ko.applyBindings` as already been called.

Comment: If the form is replaced by another form element, the call to `ko.applyBindings` will not fail. It will fail only if it called twice on the same element.

Comment: Ah right. So presumably that's because it's done on the DOM Node rather than the selector. The selector can be the same. But if the underlying DOM has changed then it's OK?

Comment: That's it, the selector is just a path but the element instance must be different.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, perhaps more 'knockouty' approach to this would be to have the button present the whole time, but use use bindings to control the visiblity of the button.

e.g

```
<input type="submit" data-bind="click: save, visible: anObservableValue" />
```

where anObservableValue is a ko.observable(false) 
that you set to true with
    anObservableValue(true) 
when you have done the inital ajax call you mentioned.

Alternatively if it is important that the button is not actually present in the dom before you make the ajax call, then use the knockout if binding wrapped around the button

```
<!-- ko if: anObervableValue -->
    <input type="submit" data-bind="click: save" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

that way the button will only be present in the dom when you want it to be, but knockout will handle the binding and will know about your save method right from the start.

This will avoid all of the fiddly binding multiple times stuff, that personally I only do when I absolutely have to